# why slice() and substr() methods in javascript doesn't work on regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, expression, slice, substr

my code is:

```
var st="man myfile=l/p/nm.mp3 yourfile=/o/mj/nnc.mp3 ou p";
var patt=/myfile.[\W|\w]*.mp3\s/;
var s=patt.exec(st);
var s2=s.slice(3,4);
alert(s2);
```

but slice() gives me nothing and substr() method gives me an error:

`Object doesn't support  this method`

Why?

Comment: `.exec` returns an object. What is your intended output?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah ! `.exec()` method

Comment: my intended output is a string. how can I convert it?

Comment: As @hooner answered, the index `0` holds the full match so `s[0]` should do it.

Comment: slice, substr are methods of arrays and not strings, Read more about these methods here http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/javascript-arrays/

To manipulate strings use indexOf();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabricio is right. Your variable `s` is a RegExp object. To access the substring you'll need to do:

```
var s2 = s[0].substr(3,4);
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3QkWX/).

Answer (score 0):

`slice`: 
  The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

`substring`:
  The substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

```
var st="man myfile=l/p/nm.mp3 yourfile=/o/mj/nnc.mp3 ou p";
var patt=/myfile.[\W|\w]*.mp3\s/;
var s=patt.exec(st);
```

`s` is now array that contains: `["myfile=l/p/nm.mp3 yourfile=/o/mj/nnc.mp3 "]`

```
var s2=s.slice(3,4);
```

Element `3` does NOT exists so it returns `null`.

About `substring` it cannot be used on array :) so u must do something like that:

```
var s2=s[0].substring(3,4);
```